# Automatically change drawer language when app resume from backstack

Tags: android, localization, kotlin, resources

I have implemented two language in my app "English" and "French" and both of them are working fine individually. When I am trying to check the language change with device language that time getting problem.

Recently my app and device language are "French". Now I am changing the device language from "French" to "English" and then open the app from backstack, app language is still in "French" thats right but In the app, navigation drawer related content changed to "English"

Below is the code for changing language which I have done in GlobalClass

```
public void changelanguage(String languageToLoad, Context context) {

            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        }
```

And below is the code for comparing language on MainActivity and Splashscreen

```
gc = GlobalClass.getInstance()
prefsWrapper = PreferencesWrapper(applicationContext)
sel_langague = prefsWrapper.getPreferenceStringValue(SipConfigManager.LANGUAGE)
println("Language Main : " + sel_langague)
var languageToLoad = ""
if (sel_langague == "0") {
     languageToLoad ="en"
} else {
     languageToLoad ="fr"
}
gc!!.changelanguage(languageToLoad, baseContext)
```

Does any one have idea for how can I resolve that problem?

Comment: Could you see language changed when restart your App?

Answer (score 5):

Check this,

```
String language = preferences.getString("language", null);
```

and this is my onclick listener of button

```
 llChangeLanguage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if (language == null) {
                LocaleHelper.setLocale(BaseActivity.this, "de");
                Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                storeLanguageInPref("en");
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else if ("kn".contentEquals(language)) {
                LocaleHelper.setLocale(BaseActivity.this, "de");
                Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                storeLanguageInPref("en");
                finish();
            } else {
                LocaleHelper.setLocale(BaseActivity.this, "kn");
                Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                storeLanguageInPref("kn");
                startActivity(intent);

                finish();
            }

        }
    });
```

and here i am storing the selected language to preference

```
 private void storeLanguageInPref(String language) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(BaseActivity.this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    editor.putString("language", language);
    editor.apply();
}
```

LocaleHelper class

```
public class LocaleHelper {

public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
    String locale = getPersistedLocale(context);
    return setLocale(context, locale);
}

public static String getPersistedLocale(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(SettingsFragment.KEY_PREF_LANGUAGE, "");
}

/**
 * Set the app's locale to the one specified by the given String.
 *
 * @param context
 * @param localeSpec a locale specification as used for Android resources (NOTE: does not
 *                   support country and variant codes so far); the special string "system" sets
 *                   the locale to the locale specified in system settings
 * @return
 */
public static Context setLocale(Context context, String localeSpec) {
    Locale locale;
    if (localeSpec.equals("system")) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            locale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
        } else {
            //noinspection deprecation
            locale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
        }
    } else {
        locale = new Locale(localeSpec);
    }
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return updateResources(context, locale);
    } else {
        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, locale);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private static Context updateResources(Context context, Locale locale) {
    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);
    configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, Locale locale) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
    }

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

    return context;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different options.

1. setting including "locale" to android:configChanges in xml. It is recommended the way of changing the language as [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) says,

> android:configChanges Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is called.
>
> Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last-resort. Please read Handling Runtime Changes for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.
>
> Any or all of the following strings are valid values for this attribute. Multiple values are separated by '|' — for example, "locale|navigation|orientation".

2. Another way is through the broadcast receiver.
   [ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED).
   You can register a BroadcastReceiver in your manifest to handle it.