# how to change language in google maps app (ios and android)?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

If you are ever traveling to a country that speaks a different language than you, especially if they also use a different writing system, you have probably discovered that the language/writing system in google maps can be an issue.

Quite simply there are times when you need to switch between the different writing systems. I find this to be especially true when working with taxi drivers to get to a location.

**Based on this google feature suggestion:**

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?visit_id=1-636588508277749030-2026148983&rd=1#!topicsearchin/maps/category$3Afeature-suggestions$20language

a lot of people are requesting a similar feature.

My first question is: is there a working solution for this problem?
2nd q: if there isn't a working solution, is there a reason that Google and others have not bothered to solve a big problem with a really simple solution?

My suggested solution: in the google maps app menu, have a list of languages you want to be able to toggle between while viewing the map. Then when viewing the map, have a place on the screen/menu to switch between these languages.

If there are no working solutions to this problem, please feel free to contact me if you're interested in helping to contact this problem.

Thanks

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726672/automatically-change-drawer-language-when-app-resume-from-backstack/49726842#49726842

Comment: Feature requests exist in Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63829150 (Android) and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828434 (iOS). Please star these feature requests and add your comments to express your interest.