# Change the language of an app depending on the user's choice

Tags: android, localization, locale

So, I have an application that needs to give the user the ability to choose the language of the app at register time.

The user registers, chooses the language from a spinner, and that information is then saved on the backend/in the SharedPreferences as a string. For example, "ro" for Romanian and "en" for English.

The flow is this - user registers and chooses a language, goes to a SMS confirmation screen, and then goes into the MainActivity, which instantiates a Fragment which populates the main screen.

It's in this fragment where I would like to see the app be displayed in the language that the user chose at registration time.

I have a working code, but it's not optimal - it doesn't work on all devices. Even weirder, code that should **not** be compatible with newer devices (Android 8) works, but if I write code specifically for those devices, it doesn't work.

I've been browsing StackOverflow all day long yesterday, and still couldn't make it work.

Here's some code snippets:

**SplashActivity** (first activity to be displayed - this takes the operating system's language and sets it for the app):

```
private void checkIsLoggedIn() {
    final UserInfo userInfo = complexPreferences.getObject("user_info", UserInfo.class);
    String language;

    if (userInfo != null) {
        language = userInfo.language;
    }
    else {
        String phoneLanguage = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        if (phoneLanguage.equals("ro")) {
            language = "ro";
        } else {
            language = "en";
        }
    }

    setLocale(language);

public void setLocale(String lang) {

    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
```

Please note that I'm aware that this block of code is obsolete for newer devices, but it's the only one that worked.

**CodeVerificationPresenter:**

```
private void callEditProfile() {
    api.editProfile(editProfileRequest)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new BaseObserver<LoginResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    super.onCompleted();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    super.onError(e);
                    if (isViewAttached())
                        getView().showError(context.getString(R.string.could_not_update_profile));
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(LoginResponse loginResponse) {
                    super.onNext(loginResponse);
                    if (loginResponse.success == 1) {
                        complexPreferences.putObject("user_info", loginResponse.userInfo);
                        if (image!=null)
                            changeImage(loginResponse.userInfo);
                        else
                            if (isViewAttached())
                                getView().requestSuccesful();
                    } else
                        if (isViewAttached() && !BaseApplication.isLogout) {
                            getView().showError(loginResponse.message);
                        }
                }
            });
}
```

Now we have the userInfo in the SharedPreferences.

**MainActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    injectDependencies();

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    drawerAdapter = component.adapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(drawerAdapter);

    if (getIntent().hasExtra("fromRegister")) {
        changeFragment(RestaurantListFragment.newInstanceFromRegister(true));
    } else {
        changeFragment(new RestaurantListFragment());
    }
}
```

The called method is `changeFragment(RestaurantListFragment.newInstanceFromRegister(true));

We end up in **RestaurantListFragment**, where this happens:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    adapter = component.adapter();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates();

    userInfo = complexPreferences.getObject("user_info", UserInfo.class);

    setLocale(userInfo.language);

public void setLocale(String lang) {
    Locale myLocale;
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = context.getApplicationContext().getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
```

Surprisingly, the code actually works, with a few exceptions (doesn't work on a Xiaomi phone, Android 8). If you choose Romanian from the language spinner in the registration, the app will be displayed in Romanian. According to a lot of code snippets I found on StackOverflow, this shouldn't have worked.

The issue is - I have no guarantee that it will work on all devices. Furthermore, not all strings work (I still have the English "Search" in a field, instead of "Cauta" in Romanian).

Do you have any advice in how to approach this? I've tried all kinds of things, and none worked, including code blocks specific on the SDK version and so on).

Thanks!

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726672/automatically-change-drawer-language-when-app-resume-from-backstack/49726842#49726842

Comment: You don't have the code for the LocaleHelper class in there.

Comment: i have updated the answer check now

Comment: Thanks, but your solution contains errors.

Comment: what errors you are getting. It is working fine for me and even the people who upvoted for the answer

Comment: Well, this doesn't do anything: public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
    String locale = getPersistedLocale(context);
    return setLocale(context, locale);
}