# Changing the app language run time without recreating the activity

Tags: android, android-activity, localization

**What I need:** I want to give option of changing language in my application to change language of my application only, not for whole phone language.

**What I did:** I tried to change the Locale at run time and It is changing the language.

**What is the Issue:** What I want is, I don't want to recreate the Activity or Fragment while changing the language.

What I have tried is like below.

**TestActivity.java**

```
    public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_dashboard, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        String selectedLang = null;

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.menu_lang_english) {
            selectedLang = "en";
            Toast.makeText(this, "English selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.menu_lang_kannada) {
            selectedLang = "fr";
            Toast.makeText(this, "French selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        changeLang(this, selectedLang);

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void changeLang(Context context, String selectedLang) {
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(selectedLang);
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
        config.locale = myLocale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        recreate();
    }
}
```

**activity_test.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".mvp.view.activity.TestActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Ask me if anything required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726672/automatically-change-drawer-language-when-app-resume-from-backstack/49726842#49726842

Comment: Upvote my answer if it has helped you

Comment: I'm trying to implement it. I have some doubts, How it will change the language without recreating views?@hasan_shaikh

Comment: Once you change the language you have to refresh your current activity

Comment: I don't want to refresh the activity. I have mentioned in question as well.@hasan_shaikh

Comment: Have a look at https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758

Comment: Let me check@DavidWasser

Comment: @DavidWasser that blog solution still does not keep app from restarting. For the poster, there does not seem to be a way to prevent app restart when a user changes their language via settings and returns back to the app. Thankfully it is rare for users to change their language settings. And perhaps you can keep things from going horribly wrong by managing your onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState

Comment: @portfoliobuilder But other big companies are doing this without app restarting. Like Amazon Prime Videos. There should be some other way to do so.

Comment: @MaulikDodia That is because that app is not native. Using a webview and/or creating a web app based in javascript and web technologies this can be possible. Facebook is another non-native app that does not reset. Additionally, this can be done if you allow the user to select language inside of the app by changing the locale and updating resources on your Configuration (this is a class), effectively this will change the String res folder the app points to. But if the user manually changes languages through Settings, your app will inevitably restart.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. And we can't add this JavaScript in our pure Java/Kotlin android code? If you know by any chance@portfoliobuilder

Comment: @portfoliobuilder I have come across the this: (https://www.techvigil.com/tips-tricks/423/differentiate-native-hybrid-app/) link. And it says, "turning on the layout bounds under drawing section in developer options, after that you will open any app, On that app if you find lot of squares that means it is developed in native environment otherwise not". I tried and found that **Amazon Prime** is a native app. Hence question stands, how to change language without recreation?

Comment: @MaulikDodia that trick works for apps made in PhoneGap, Titanium, Cordova, ect. But there are instances where it does not work like apps created with ReactNative. Look at the last comment in the article YOU posted referring to how Instagram is a non-native app and is full of rectangles. Don't believe everything you read. Trust a fellow professional app developer. I am letting you know with sincerity, after developing and publishing dozens of professional apps that have multi-language feature requirements. Your lifecycle will reset, you can only manage it.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder My bad, I did not read comment. I was just trying to figure it out. Thanks for enlightening me.